# Spring Security Authentication using MyBatis

Tags: spring-security, mybatis

I am trying to perform Spring Security Authentication using MyBatis.

My spring-security file looks as follows

```
        <global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" />

       <beans:bean id="myUserService"                    
                 class="com.service.CustomService" />

            <authentication-manager>
                <authentication-provider user-service-ref="myUserService" />
            </authentication-manager>
```

My CustomService class `implements UserDetailsService` and in the `loadUserByUsername` method , I am using my MyBatis Dao to load the Users from the DB.

```
@Autowired
private MyBatisDao dao;
```

In my Controller class I am using the same annotation , and in that case it returns the proper object.

But when I use the same in the CustomService  class it returns `null`.

I am unable to understand the reason for it. Am i missing something. Please help

Any example of Spring Authentication using MyBatis would help, I can understand it and then maybe figure out the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue solved by taking an alternative approach in constructing the MyBatis Object.

I created a singleton class which returns the SqlSessionFactory Object, and using the same in my code for calling the Mapper Interfaces methods.

Sample code snippet below

```
InputStream myBatisConfigStream = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("config.xml"); 

    if (null == sqlSessionFactory){

        sqlSessionFactory = new SqlSessionFactoryBuilder().build(myBatisConfigStream);
        sqlSessionFactory.getConfiguration().addMapper(IOMapper.class);
    }

    try {

        myBatisConfigStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    public static SqlSessionFactory getSqlSessionFactory() {

    return sqlSessionFactory;
}
```

The config.xml file contains only the dataSource.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I fix this issue by another - not recommended way.

In this case, @controller can treat the db work right, 
so I do basic auth in controller and send that result to custom service. 
Custom service has no valid auth function in this case.
If useename and password is valid, custom service is called, 
and that just returns dummy auth result.
If username and password is invalid, i just didn't call the auth in controller.

Though it's not quite right way, it works fine with some special treat for user role.
I want to know there's a better way to solve this problem, 
but i have no time to find, right now.